# Метод итератора next() возвращает Object, а не указанный тип

Tags: java

Реализовал `Iterator`, но метод `next()` возвращает почему-то тип `Object`, хотя я указал возвращаемый тип `Task`.

```
ArrayTaskList atl = new ArrayTaskList();
atl.add(t);
atl.add(t1);

Iterator i = atl.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(i.next());
    }
```

Код метода `next()`:

```
@Override
public Task next() {
    int i = cursor;
    if (i > size()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    cursor++;
    return arrayTask[secondCursor = i];
}
```

Comment: Вы используете некий не стандартный класс ArrayTaskList, мы не знаем как он реализован и почему вы ожидаете что там будет корректный Iterator. И как вы поверяете тип возвращаемого объекта?

Comment: Покажите код метода `ArrayTaskList.iterator()`

Answer (score 1):

Вы не дженерифицируете итератор:

```
List<Element> list = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator<Element> = list.iterator();
```

Comment: У автора вопроса класс ArrayTaskList, а не List. Возможно он уже типизирован.

Comment: @Vartlok скорее всего. Только ответ про вторую строку, а не про первую.